# How to store many data for single user to the database with ASP.Net in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently doing an internship program and was required to create a page that allow users to fill up a document to replace traditional document paper. The problem is that it is quite a lengthy data (with some that will need to write an essay at some point) to store to database. How exactly do i organize all the data that will be stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data by using either VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX), since these data type of field allow to store up to 2 GB of data. If your data exceeds 2 GB, then FILESTREAM could be the solution.

Comment: This is not the solution i was looking for. What i meant was that how do i organize the data that i will received so everything will be viewable as it will be bunch of paragraphs. if i were to put all the data in table, it will be messy.